# Run method with BackgroundWorker on second Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, backgroundworker

Let's imagine that we have two Forms: `MainForm` and `WaitingForm`. I want to pass, from `MainForm`, to the `WaitingForm` the method to run in background using `BackgroundWorker`.

Now, I'm doing things that way:

`MainForm.cs`:

```
public partial class MainForm: Form
{
    private void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var waitingFrm = new WaitingForm();
        waitingFrm.DoWork = (o, args) => this.LongRunningOperation(this, new DoWorkEventArgs("foo bar"));
        waitingFrm.OnWorkCompleted = (o, args) => MessageBox.Show("Finished!");
        waitingFrm.Show();
        waitingFrm.Run(); // should execute LongRunningOperation, method below.
    }

    private void LongRunningOperation(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Running long operation!....");
        // some long running stuff here;
    }
}
```

`WaitingForm.cs`

```
public partial class WaitingForm: Form
{
    private BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    public DoWorkEventHandler DoWork { get; set; }
    public RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler OnWorkCompleted { get; set; }

    public WaitingForm()
    {
        this.worker.DoWork += DoWork;
        this.worker.RunWorkerCompleted += OnWorkCompleted;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        this.worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

But after `waitingFrm.Run();` my `LongRunningOperation` is not executed.

Comment: Why do you need the background worker to be on a form?

Comment: Becaues I would like to reuse WaitingForm for other things to run in background.

Comment: WaitingForm - Windows Service?

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata: No, it's normal WinForm, it's not any service.

Comment: Why is the constructor named `FrmWaiting`?

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata: Fixed, sorry. Should be: WaitingForm().

Comment: @dario I mean why do you need a form for things to run in the background?  Also, why do you want to reause the same BackgroundWorker object instead of just creating them as needed?

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata: Bacause I would like to create some common form for that sort of things, and only pass the methods to run. This is only informative form, that somethings happend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your WaitingForm I'd do:

```
public event DoWorkEventHandler DoWork {
    add { worker.DoWork += value; } 
    remove { worker.DoWork += value; }
}
```

(Instead of the get;set; property).
And then in your main window `btnImport_Click` handler just:

```
waitingFrm.DoWork += LongRunnignOperation;
```

And the same for completed handler.  Your syntax seems overly complicated.  This is just a clean way to expose an event (in this case on your waitingform) and the pass event handler through to the real handler (in this case worker.DoWork).  It is equivalent to

```
 waitingFrm.worker.DoWork += LongRunnignOperation;
```

which would do just as well.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to pass, from MainForm, to the WaitingForm the method to run
>   in background using BackgroundWorker

I would in this case

- declare an event in `WaitingForm`
- before `Form1` shows `WaitingForm` subscribes to that event
- when *long running operation* has to be runned `WaitingForm` raise an event, `Form1` gets it and
  `Form1` runs its method in other thread.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case you want all of the work to happen in `MainForm` and it looks like `WaitingForm` is just a display for the user.  If that's the case then I would just put the `BackgroundWorker` in the `MainForm` and use the event to call into `WaitingForm`

```
public partial class MainForm: Form
{
  private void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var waitingForm = new WaitingForm();
    waitingForm.Show();
    var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += (o, args) => this.LogRunningOperation(o, args);
    worker.OnWorkComplete += (o, args) => {
      waitingForm.Close();
      worker.Dispose();
    };
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
  }

  private void LongRunningOperation(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
    MessageBox.Show("Running long operation!....");
    // some long running stuff here;
  }
}
```

Comment: Either you're missing a brace or C# got an awesome ability to declare functions inside functions =).

Comment: Yes, but now btnImport procedure takes control of: 1) Creating WaitingForm 2) Creating BackgroundWorker, and connecting that into one. A little bit messy IMHO.

Comment: @dario i actually find this much simpler.  It significantly reduces the complexity of `WaitingForm` and restricts the usage of the `BackgroundWorker` events to the minimal area needed

Answer (score 1):

So, the simple answer is that. Your code is not working because the mainform is not *seeing* the BackgroundWorker object instance events. Instead of doing:

```
    this.worker.DoWork += DoWork;
    this.worker.RunWorkerCompleted += OnWorkCompleted;
```

in WaitingForm - InitializeComponent(), do this instead in mainForm like this:

```
    waitingFrm.worker.DoWork += waitingFrm.DoWork;
    waitingFrm.worker.RunWorkerCompleted += waitingFrm.OnWorkCompleted;
```

Comment: I don't want to make my worker as public, I think that it's better to hide this.

Comment: The important thing is that you understood the problem and solved it... you could make it internal if you wanted to use this approach. It's a matter of choice.